# Reading input from a text file into an arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

I have a text file, that I'm supposed to read data from. The data should then be used to set a level to pass:

- > 20 → very good
- between 12-20 → OK
- < 12 → failed

The `.txt` file looks like this

```
X;20
Y;12
```

The problem is, that when I read from the file, and add it to an `ArrayList`, it only reads the columns. In other words, the result is that index `0` contains `X;Y`, and index `1` contains `20;12`. What I need is for index `0` to contain `[X 20]` and index `1` to contain `[Y 12]`.

My code is:

```
BufferedReader assignment = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(assignmentFile));
ArrayList<String> assignmentArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
String item;
while ((item = assignment.readLine()) != null) {
    assignmentArrayList.add(item);
    String[] itemSplit = item.split(";");
    String passWithDistinction = itemSplit[0];
    String pass = itemSplit[1];
    System.out.println(passWithDistinction + pass);
}
```

Comment: Show your code please.

Comment: Why do you use ArrayList instead of a simple `String` array?

Comment: Your code works. I can't understand what you're looking for.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is add the number into a specific index in the arraylist so if i .get(1) I get "20", so that i can set the level for pass with that number.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are still looking for suggestions on this. I'd be happy to help but I really don't understand your question. You say that you are reading the file to obtain the two numbers that define the distinction and pass marks. But then what is the X and Y for? And why do you say that you want your ArrayList to have [X 20] and [Y 12] as members?

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the file's content to a `String` array like this:

```
File assignmentFile = new File("C:/Dir1/Dir2/file.txt");
ReadFile assignment = new ReadFile(assignmentFile.getAbsolutePath());
String[] lines = assignment.OpenFile();
```

If you want to set the strings so they won't have the ';' symbol, add these lines:

```
for(int i=0; i<lines.length(); i++)
    lines[i].replace(";", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you want to read the text file and end up with the two numbers that define the distinction and pass mark. I'm not exactly sure what the X and Y are for and why you want to store them - I'd be happy to help with that if you want.

If you know the text file has two (and only two) lines then you don't really need a while loop. Simpler would be to just read and parse this lines in turn:

```
String[] distinctionLine = assignment.readLine().split(";");
int distinction = Integer.parseInt(distinctionLine[1]);
String[] passLine = assignment.readLine().split(";");
int pass = Integer.parseInt(passLine[1]);
```

There are a number of exceptions and error conditions you should be checking for but hopefully you get the idea.